# ssh - getting metadata of many remote files

Tags: python, ssh, scalability, finder

there's a remote file system which i can access using ssh.

i need to:

1. scan this file system to find all the files newer than a given datetime.
2. retrieve a list of those files' names, size, and modified_time_stamp

some restrictions:

1. i can't upload a script to this remote server. i can only run commands through ssh
2. there could be well over 100k of files in the remote server, and this process should happen at least once a minute, so the number of ssh calls should be minimal, and preferably equal to 1

i've already managed to get (1) using this:

```
`touch -am -t {timestamp} /tmp/some_filename; find {path} -newer /tmp/some_filename; rm /tmp/some_filename')`
```

and i thought i can move in the direction of piping the results into "xargs ls -l" and then parsing the results to extract the size and timestamp from there, but then i found [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

also, i'm running the command using python (i.e. it's not just a command line), so it's ok to do some post processing on the results coming from the ssh command

Comment: running a big find on 100,000 files once a minute seems ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing or modifying your python script on the server side as follows:

1. When no data has been acquired in a while, acquire initial data using the touch/find script you provided and making calls on the found files to get the needed properties
2. Then, in the python script on the server, subscribe to inotify() data to get updates.
3. When a remote connects and needs all this data, provide the latest update from combining 1+2

inotify is a system call supported in Linux that allows you to monitor file system events on a directory in real time.

See:

https://serverfault.com/questions/30292/automatic-notification-of-new-or-changed-files-in-a-folder-or-share

http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify